# On the possible vectorization of a nested for loop

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider two identical 3D arrays, `a1` and `a2`.  In this small example, I used random arrays of shape `(10, 2, 2)`.  I want to be able to `vstack` all of the 2x2 2D arrays in `a1` with all of the 2x2 2D arrays in `a2`, and produce a 3D array that holds the stacked 2D arrays.

Because my actual `a1` and `a2` arrays (always having the same shape) are typically of size about `(100000, 20, 20)`,   I usually choose to just study a small subset of the `vstack`ed 2D arrays.  For this reason, I only examine small consecutive 2D array sets from `a1` and `a2` as specified by variables `a1_start`, `a1_stop`, `a2_start`, `a2_stop`.

The code below works fine, though I still need to do some cleanup, etc:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 2, 2))
a2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 2, 2))

a1_start = 3
a1_stop = 5
a2_start = 0
a2_stop = 3

out = np.zeros(((a1_stop - a1_start)*(a2_stop - a2_start), 2*2, 2), dtype=int)
n=0

for p in a1[a1_start: a1_stop]:
    for q in a2[a2_start: a2_stop]:
        out[n] = np.vstack((p, q))
        n += 1
out
```

QUESTION:  Because my actual arrays are quite large, ***I'm wondering if the above code can be vectorized***.  I'd  like to be able to compare execution speeds.

Comment: repeated `vstack` is worse than list append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky:

```
arr = np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(
    a1[a1_start:a1_stop, None],
    a2[None, a2_start:a2_stop]
))
out = arr.reshape(-1, *arr.shape[2:])
```

Comment: Thanks to both Chrysophylaxs and Nick ODell.   Both solutions were excellent, with the 1st named coder being just a 'hair' faster.  Both solutions taught me a lot.

Comment: `dstack` is just `concatenate` on a 3rd axis (expending dimensions if needed).  So the amount of work/copying should be similar.

Comment: Assume that from array a1 we choose 2d arrays g and h (in that order),  and from a2 we choose 2d arrays i, j, k in that order.  I notice that Chryophylaxs' solution produce output in the order g over i, h over i, g over j, h over j, g over k, h over k.  
Nick ODell's solution shows the same output in the order  g over i, g over j, g over k, h over i, h over j, h over k.    Though order of the 2d arrays was not in the original question, I'd prefer Nick's order.   Can your solution be adjusted to match that order as well?  Much thanks

Comment: @user109387 I have included an additional swapaxes!

Comment: Realized a bit later I could have just reordered the Nones...

Comment: Yes! - I just found that myself.   Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
q_range = np.arange(a2_start, a2_stop)
p_range = np.arange(a1_start, a1_stop)
p, q = np.meshgrid(p_range, q_range, indexing='ij')
q = q.flatten()
p = p.flatten()
out = np.concatenate((a1[p], a2[q]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice work.  See Chrysophylaxs comment as well.